# An efficient way to calculate the mean of each column or row of non-zero elements

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy array for ratings given by users on movies. The rating is between 1 and 5, while 0 means that a user does not rate on a movie. I want to calculate the average rating of each movie, and the average rating of each user. In other words, I will calculate the mean of each column or row of non-zero elements.

Is there an efficient numpy array function to handle this case? I know manually iterating ratings by columns or rows can solve the problem.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How is the array organized? Can you give a code sample of how you load the array? If you load it from a file, please also post a sample of the file format.

Answer (score 9):

Since the values to discard are 0, you can compute the mean manually by doing the sum along an axis and then dividing by the number of non zeros elements (along the same axis):

```
a = np.array([[8.,9,7,0], [0,0,5,6]])
a.sum(1)/(a != 0).sum(1)
```

results in:

```
array([ 8. ,  5.5])
```

as you can see, the zeros are not considered in the mean.

Answer (score 5):

You could make use of `np.nanmean`, after converting all `0` values to `np.nan`. Note that `np.nanmean` is only available in `numpy 1.8`.

```
import numpy as np

ratings = np.array([[1,4,5,0],
                    [2,0,3,0],
                    [4,0,0,0]], dtype=np.float)


def get_means(ratings):
    ratings[np.where(ratings == 0)] = np.nan

    user_means = np.nanmean(ratings, axis=1)
    movie_means = np.nanmean(ratings, axis=0)

    return {'user_means' : user_means, 'movie_means' : movie_means}
```

Result:

```
>>> get_means(ratings)
{'movie_means': array([ 2.33333333,  4.        ,  4.        ,         nan]), 

'user_means': array([ 3.33333333,  2.5       ,  4.        ])}
```

Comment: `nanmean` was added to numpy in 1.8, but there is also a version in `scipy.stats` that has been there quite a while.

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative is to use a masked array, with the 0 values masked.  For example (using @Akavali's sample data):

```
In [30]: ratings = np.array([[1,4,5,0],
   ....:                     [2,0,3,0],
   ....:                     [4,0,0,0]], dtype=np.float)
```

Create the masked version of `ratings`, using `ratings==0` as the mask:

```
In [31]: mratings = np.ma.masked_array(ratings, mask=ratings==0)

In [32]: mratings
Out[32]: 
masked_array(data =
 [[1.0 4.0 5.0 --]
 [2.0 -- 3.0 --]
 [4.0 -- -- --]],
             mask =
 [[False False False  True]
 [False  True False  True]
 [False  True  True  True]],
       fill_value = 1e+20)
```

Now compute the mean along each axis:

```
In [33]: mratings.mean(axis=0)
Out[33]: 
masked_array(data = [2.3333333333333335 4.0 4.0 --],
             mask = [False False False  True],
       fill_value = 1e+20)

In [34]: mratings.mean(axis=1)
Out[34]: 
masked_array(data = [3.3333333333333335 2.5 4.0],
             mask = [False False False],
       fill_value = 1e+20)
```