# How to calculate the mean of ratings of each user?

Tags: arrays, python-2.7, pandas, mean

Assume I have a dataset like this:

```
userID productID rating
a          i       5
b          i       4
c          i       4 
a          j       3
b          j       5
```

The question is, how can I calculate the mean rating of each user? 
I saw [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21057434/an-efficient-way-to-calculate-the-mean-of-each-column-or-row-of-non-zero-element), but I didn't quite understand it. I would really appreciate your time, if you show some guidance.

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). All relevant parts should be in your questions rather that  in links (that currently don't work).

Comment: I double checked the links, they work. I guess the example I gave is minimal. I tried though. Sorry, I am a beginner.

Comment: Ok. One of links works now. The other still gives *Sorry, something went wrong.* This might resolve itself. But the workbook is really large. You will get the quickest and best answers when you post self contained question and your attempts so far.

Comment: Thank you. I removed the link. Let's concentrate on the example above. As it is very close to data I'm working on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I work in an IPython Notebook.

Let's assume you have this file `user_ratings.csv`:

```
userID productID rating
a          i       5
b          i       4
c          i       4
a          j       3
b          j       5
```

The example in the link uses pandas. So import pandas:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd
```

Read your file into a dataframe:

```
In [2]: df = pd.read_csv('user_ratings.csv', delim_whitespace=True)
df
```

[image]

Group by the user and calculate the mean for each:

```
In [2]: df.groupby('userID').mean()
```

[image]

You can also create a new column in `df` named `user_avg_rating` an assign the mean score of each user to it:

```
In [3]:  df['user_avg_rating'] = df.groupby('userID')['rating'].transform('mean')
         df
```

[image]

The method `transform` takes your grouped object and creates a series:

```
In [4]:  df.groupby('userID')['rating'].transform('mean')

    0    4.0
    1    4.5
    2    4.0
    3    4.0
    4    4.5
    dtype: float64
```

This series is assigned to the column `user_avg_rating`.

Comment: Thank you very much! Another liiiiiittle question: how to add this average  rating column to the first dataset?  I assume the code will be something like this? -- `df['user_avg_rating'] = df.groupby('user_id')['user_id'].transform('mean')`

Comment: Added an example for this to my question.

Comment: You can [accept](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) an answer if it solves your problem.

Comment: Thank you for helping me, Mike!

Comment: Dear Mike, the codes are working perfectly, many thanks again!